# memcpy gives different output in different compiler

Tags: c, gcc, memcpy

Please consider the below program

```
/* Demonstrating memset(), memcpy(), and memmove(). */
 #include <stdio.h>
 #include <string.h>
 char message1[60] = "Four score and seven years ago ...";
 char message2[60] = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz";
 char temp[60];
 main()
 {
    printf("\nmessage1[] before memset():\t%s", message1);
    memset(message1 + 5, '@', 10);
    printf("\nmessage1[] after memset():\t%s", message1);

    strcpy(temp, message2);
    printf("\n\nOriginal message: %s", temp);
    memcpy(temp + 4, temp + 16, 10);
    printf("\nAfter memcpy() without overlap:\t%s", temp);
    strcpy(temp, message2);
    memcpy(temp + 6, temp + 4, 10);
    printf("\nAfter memcpy() with overlap:\t%s", temp);

    strcpy(temp, message2);
    printf("\n\nOriginal message: %s", temp);
    memmove(temp + 4, temp + 16, 10);
    printf("\nAfter memmove() without overlap:\t%s", temp);
    strcpy(temp, message2);
    memmove(temp + 6, temp + 4, 10);
    printf("\nAfter memmove() with overlap:\t%s\n", temp);

 }
```

Now consider the outputs in 2 different compilers

```
ramesh@ramesh-K56CA:~/cpract$ ./a.out 

message1[] before memset(): Four score and seven years ago ...
message1[] after memset():  Four @@@@@@@@@@seven years ago ...

Original message: abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz
After memcpy() without overlap: abcdqrstuvwxyzopqrstuvwxyz
After memcpy() with overlap:    abcdefefefghijklqrstuvwxyz

Original message: abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz
After memmove() without overlap:    abcdqrstuvwxyzopqrstuvwxyz
After memmove() with overlap:   abcdefefghijklmnqrstuvwxyz

ramesh@ramesh-K56CA:~/cpract$ uname -a
Linux ramesh-K56CA 3.13.0-24-generic #47-Ubuntu SMP Fri May 2 23:30:00 UTC 2014 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

Now consider output in another compiler

```
blc-10-6{8}: gcc memmove.c
blc-10-6{9}: ./a.out

message1[] before memset():     Four score and seven years ago ...
message1[] after memset():      Four @@@@@@@@@@seven years ago ...

Original message: abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz
After memcpy() without overlap: abcdqrstuvwxyzopqrstuvwxyz
After memcpy() with overlap:    abcdefefefijijmnqrstuvwxyz

Original message: abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz
After memmove() without overlap:        abcdqrstuvwxyzopqrstuvwxyz
After memmove() with overlap:   abcdefefghijklmnqrstuvwxyz

blc-10-6{10}: uname -a
Linux blc-10-6 2.6.9-42.ELsmp #1 SMP Wed Jul 12 23:27:17 EDT 2006 i686 i686 i386 GNU/Linux
```

Can someone please help me to understand the behavior of memcpy for overlapping regions of memory?

Comment: From `man memcpy`: "The memcpy() function copies n bytes from memory area src to memory area dest.  **The memory areas must not overlap.**  Use memmove(3) if the memory areas do overlap."

Answer (score 4):

The behavior of function `memcpy()` with overlapping regions of memory is **undefined**. The actually observed result may depend on the specific implementation and in pure theory, it is allowed to [fly demons out of your nose](http://www.catb.org/jargon/html/N/nasal-demons.html).

In practice, the `memcpy` function copies from one buffer to the other either from low addresses to high addresses or the other way round, and it may be optimized to copy bytes by 2, 4 or 8, leading to a large variety of behaviors.

The `memcpy()` function's requirement that the addresses accessed through one pointer argument and the other are never the same is expressed in plain English in the C99 standard:

> If copying takes place between objects that overlap, the behavior is undefined. (7.21.2.1:2)

This requirement is also summarized by the `restrict` keyword in `memcpy()`'s prototype:

```
void *memcpy(void *restrict dest, const void *restrict src, size_t n);
```

Although the exact meaning of `restrict` [refers to the actual implementation, so it's not a self-contained description](http://blog.frama-c.com/index.php?post/2012/08/02/restrict-not-modular).

A specification of `memcpy()`'s requirements in a [specification language designed for this sort of thing](http://frama-c.com/acsl_tutorial_index.html) looks like this:

```
/*@ requires valid_dst: \valid(((char*)dest)+(0..n - 1));
  @ requires valid_src: \valid_read(((char*)src)+(0..n - 1));
  @ requires \separated(((char *)dest)+(0..n-1),((char *)src)+(0..n-1));
  @ assigns ((char*)dest)[0..n - 1] \from ((char*)src)[0..n-1];
  ...
  @*/
void *memcpy(void *restrict dest, const void *restrict src, size_t n);
```

In this contract for `memcpy()`, the `\separated(((char *)dest)+(0..n-1),((char *)src)+(0..n-1))` requirement expresses exactly which memory zones are supposed not to overlap.

If you want to from a memory zone to another that you do not know for sure that it doesn't overlap the first one, use `memmove()`. This function takes the same arguments as `memcpy()` but is guaranteed to work even if overlap exists.

Comment: ***[A reference](http://www.catb.org/jargon/html/N/nasal-demons.html)*** may be useful here...

Comment: @ryyker I was going to add many references. Thanks for this one. I have one I think good for restrict.

Comment: @rici Do you mean because of all the \ characters in my answer? These are ACSL keywords. It was decided to use a leading \ in each of them in order to avoid any possible clash with an existing identifier from a C program being specified a posteriori. No relationship to LaTeX (except that \ is a good candidate to avoid clashes when building both on top of C and on top of natural languages used in documents, I guess)

Comment: @PascalCuoq: In part. I saw your answer before you edited it, and at first glance it looked like the sort of stuff I used to type before I realized that latex here is just a no-go. But I'm still wishful...